# USB Headphones : No sound / Crackling sound

Tags: sound, usb, 20.04, headphones, headset

I've bought Bowers & Wilkins PX7 headphones. It doesn't work using USB on Ubuntu.

Using Ubuntu and bluetooth, or audio jack, the headphones works well.
Using Windows 10 and USB, the headphones works well.

I d'like too use them with USB on Ubuntu because that recharge them in parallel.

Problems :

- On Chrome : The videos are played too fast and there's no sound (Youtube & Twitch).
- On Firefox : The videos are played too fast and there's a crackling sound (Youtube & Twitch).
- On VLC : No sound

I've tried :

- Under Ubuntu 20.04 & 18.04
- Fully update ubuntu (yesterday)
- Restarting my comuter multiple times
- Setting them as default audio device
- Using PulseAudio tweaks

  - The headphone appears and is set as fallback
  - I've tried switching between Analog and Digital ;
  - Restarting pulseaudio ;
  - Reinstalling pulseaudio
- Using alsamixer

  - They were already unmute
  - I've tried to force reload ;
  - Reinstall alsamixer
- Speaker-test : I can hear sound but it's "segmented", there are irregularities
- I've added pcie_aspm=off in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
- Setting devices as default in /etc/asound.conf

Does someone have any ideas ?
I run out of ideas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.

In /etc/pulse/daemon.conf edit these lines (don't forget abut uncoment):

```
default-sample-rate = 96000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

After that restart pulseaudio:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

To check what have changed, find `sample spec:` in:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
```

should be:

```
sample spec: s24le 2 k 96000 Hz
```

For me that solution works well.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works well !